# Awk command to check if a particular string is present in a file, if present return the column names where this string is present

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

Using the following awk command, I am able to check if a particular string is present in a file or not.

```
grep -R "statistics" <Filename>
```

But the output I am looking for is I need to find out the columns in which this string is present. Is there a way to extend this command so that it can return me the column names where this string is present.

I tried the following command, but I am not getting the desired output

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if ($i = "statistics") print i } }' <filename>
```

There are around 1500 columns in my input file. It is a tab separated file with column headers included.

Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    array[i]=$i
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="statistics"){
      print "Line number is: " FNR ", column number is: "i ",column heading is:" array[i]
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using a variable which will have value of string which we want to search for.

```
awk -v word="statistics" '
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    array[i]=$i
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i==word){
       print "Line number is: " FNR ", column number is: "i",column heading is:" array[i]
    }
  }
}' Input_file
```

Above both solutions will print line number along with column number.

---

---

***3rd solution:*** To print only column number try following:

```
awk 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){array[i]=$i}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="statistics"){print i,array[i]}}}' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** variant of 3rd solution with a variable approach.

```
awk -v word="statistics" 'FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){array[i]=$i}}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==word){print i,array[i]}}}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:***

- 1st and 2nd solution will give Line number, column number and header name.
- 3rd and 4th solution will give column number and header name.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for your answers. This really helped a lot and I was able to move forward with my analysis. Appreciate your time in solving my question(even though it was half baked) and not wasting time in pointing out the mistakes in my question unlike others.

Comment: Any idea how to escape the "=" in awk command? the backslash is not working. if($i=="statistics="). I need to escape the "=" after the statistics keyword. Get this warning while using backslash - awk: warning: escape sequence `\=' treated as plain `='

Comment: @Shash, you need not to escape that, it doesn't have special meaning(`=`). You could also open a new thread with question and lemme know then, will check complete question there then.